# Can git be built with VC++?

Tags: windows, git, visual-c++

I know about [Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) which provides a git shell in an [msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) shell. But is there any option of building git using the Microsoft VC++ toolchain?

Comment: I highly doubt that this is possible, as Git relies on a POSIX interface and quite a number of Linux/Unix libraries. That is why msysgit was introduced, after all, it packages all the dependencies. I have no references for this, though, so I am not going to post this as an answer.

Comment: https://github.com/gitster/git/tree/master/compat/vcbuild

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: Take a look at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/. They ported a whole lot of GNU tools which probably have such dependencies. What makes git special in that respect?

Comment: GNU for Windows is compiled using MinGW, so that's not a good example (after all, msysgit DOES exist for Windows). But the link @Banthar postet proves me wrong about my previous statement. I think this should be an answer!

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: Yes you are right. For some reason I thought it was built with VC++

Answer (score 1):

Based on Banthar's comment above:

Apparently the git source tree contains a directory with scripts and instructions to build with VC++:
https://github.com/gitster/git/tree/master/compat/vcbuild

Answer (score 1):

The Git for Windows build tree (msysGit) provides all the unix utilities that are required to build and run git. Normally this is built using gcc as this is open and free however the necessary compatability code required to build the git binaries with MSVC is present too. If you start a Visual Studio command prompt then run the msys.bat command from the msysGit tree you will have a bash shell where 'cl' runs the msvc compiler. Run the /bin/msvc-build script to initialize the tree for building with the Microsoft toolchain. This clones an additional repo of compatability files and sets the config.mak script.
After that `make MSVC=1` should be enough. The script above is configured for the free visual studio express compiler I think, but I've used some version of this to build with VS2010's C compiler.

So in summary: create a msysGit build tree using the net-intaller and use the script provided to re-configure it to build with the msvc toolchain.

Comment: while the `make MSVC=1` will make using the msvc compiler, of recent the --gui option, which builds the .sln, produces a project that fails to compile in the VS2010 IDE.